# SolrNet query to get records between to fields value

Tags: solr, solrnet

hi guys i have started working on a project which need solr implemtation for searching.

I am using SolrNet Lib and my question is:
I have two field in solr index Maxsal and Minsal and i have Currentsal parameter which contains salary amount. What i want is, get all records which satisfy this condition:

```
currentsal< Maxsal  && currentsal> Minsal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Solr range query. It should allow to create query like this

minsal:[* TO PARAM] AND maxsal:[PARAM TO *]

For more information look here - http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-query-syntax.html

Comment: Mysterion, i have two fields MINSAL and MAXSAL and a parameter. I want  only those records who's MINSAL field is smaller then the parameter value and MAXSAL is greater then parameter.

Comment: No. Let me clarify. You have param SAL=600
quiery MINSAL[0 TO 600] and MAXSAL[600 to 100000] will match record that exactly you want (according to your question)

Comment: "Problem is i have a limit of 1500 on MAXSAL and here records which are greater then 1500 will also displayed"

You don't have limit of 1500 on MAXSAL. The limit is your entered param currentsal

Comment: Maxsal and Minsal are datafield of database and index (these fields are not fixed), so they have some values and i want only those records which between these fields. Sql Query would be look like this:                select * from Jobs where (MinSAL <= 500 and MaxSal >= 500)

Comment: As usual, depends on API. My answer is library independent and could be tested on Solr Admin UI. Your solution more depends on Solrnet

Answer (score 0):

Never noticed that Query() take string parameter too.

So,
Solr.Query("MaxSal<="+parameter && MinSal>=parameter")